# Make Android OptionsMenu not Clickable

Tags: android, menu, android-menu, android-optionsmenu

How do we make an options menu not clickable?

Setting the enabled property to false only prevent the user from invoking any click actions but it is still clickable.

Thanks.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/AxsTTDmnAyE

Answer (score 1):

You can only disable MenuItem but there is no function like setClickable(false). For Example that function gives for Buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You can Override public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu), and set the menu id that you want to be disable

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if(......){
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_email).setEnabled(false);
    }
    if(......){
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_call).setEnabled(false);
    }
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```